# In Selenium SendKeys() doesn't trigger auto-updating field while normal typing does

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to automate box, that displays and auto updates data under it depending on what you type into it.

For example, when I type "Joh" it will display "John One" "John Two" in drop down menu, as soon as I have typed at least 3 letters into box.

When I type with keyboard it works fine, but when I use SendKeys("Joh"), no auto update happens, no data is shown.

Using waits or sending only one letter at a time didn't help.

What could cause it? Are there some other options to send text that could work in this case?

Comment: I tried: SendKeys(John) >  SendKeys(keys.backspace) >SendKeys(n), for example- but that also did not work

Comment: At a guess, your page has JavaScript code to search dynamically on any keypress, and SendKeys does not trigger the event that triggers the search. You're going to need to find the JavaScript code that populates your dropdown menu, then work out how to force Selenium to trigger that specific event.

Comment: @George can you scroll through a list after text is entered? sounds like you may need to implement it like a dropdown select.

Comment: I would suggest looking into running JavascriptExecuter in your script to kick off the js that will do the auto update after the third letter is typed (could put it in a loop so it runs after every subsequent letter as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At a guess, your page has JavaScript code to search dynamically on any keypress, and SendKeys does not trigger the event that triggers the search. You're going to need to find the JavaScript code that populates your dropdown menu, then work out how to force Selenium to trigger that specific event." – Kate Paulk 17 hours ago

This worked, i got event to trigger using selenium.interactions.Actions to simulate keyDown/Up (which was needed for autoupdate to trigger) after sending text with sendKeys

Using JSExecutor or EventFiringWebDriver didnt work in this case.

Heres an example in C#:

```
        var a = new Actions(driver);
        a.KeyDown(Keys.LeftShift).KeyUp(Keys.LeftShift);
        var s = a.Build();
        s.Perform();
```

Comment: Helpful answer, but can you provide code. All the key down and key up info I find is for arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

Instead if using **WebDriver** use the **EventFiringWebDriver** and sendkeys will work without any issue and fire the text change event as well.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because WebDriver is designed in a way that it instantly performs the action but EventFiringWebdriver is designed in a way that it tries to simulate exact user interaction and fires the associated events.

Comment: The event firing is on the code side, not the browser side. EFWD allows you to place listeners on events and perform actions every time one happens.

Answer (score 0):

Autoupdate happens AFTER you finish typing, right? I think you need to end the string with TAB ("\t") to leave the input field, so all related events can fire.

Comment: No, it updates during typing

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inspect to know which event fire when typing on the textbox, try to fire that event using JS or JQuery, then force Selenium execute script.

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend after SendKeys to fire an event `fireEvent(locator, blur)`.

From documentation:

```
fireEvent(locator, eventName)
Arguments:
    locator - an element locator
    eventName - the event name, e.g. "focus" or "blur"
Explicitly simulate an event, to trigger the **corresponding "onevent" handler**.
```

SendKeys does not do the same thing as your keyboard does and the text is injected by Selenium javascipts, but no key is really pressed.